# free function result confusion

Tags: c, memory, dynamic

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int *ptr,size,i;
printf("Enter the size :\n");
scanf("%d",&size);
ptr=calloc(size,sizeof(int));
printf("Here it is allocation:\n");
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
printf("%d\n",*(ptr+i));
printf("Enter the numbers:\n");
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
scanf("%d",(ptr+i));
printf("your numbers:\n");
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
printf("%d\n",*(ptr+i));
free(ptr);
printf("after free:\n");
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
printf("%d\n",*(ptr+i));
}
```

This is my test piece of code.Here i created dynamic memory using calloc() which return base address of memory and it will be initialized by 0.After i assigned the value while run time .After that i deallocate the memory.But the result look like this
Enter the size :
5
Here it is allocation:
0
0
0
0
0
Enter the numbers:
3
65
2
32
1
your numbers:
3
65
2
32
1
after free:
0
0
2
32
1

First two value only getting zero..Other values are remains same.I had confused here

Comment: Don't act surprised by *anything* when you invoke *undefined behavior* (which is exactly what you're doing by dereferencing memory after free'ing it).

Comment: @Abdul Asik Using an invalid pointer to access memory results in undefined behavior.

Comment: OT: you should indent your code properly

Comment: When you free the memory, you say “I no longer need it and will not use it again”.   When you try to print it again, you are reneging on your promise.  Don't try to access freed memory.

Answer (score 2):

Definition of `free` from the C standard spec:

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
> deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is
> a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not
> match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or
> if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
> behavior is undefined.

There is no guarantee that zeros will be written out to the block of memory passed to `free`. Most importantly, once you call `free`, you don't own that block of memory (you have given it back to the OS). You are invoking [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by trying to access memory you do not own anymore.